# How to create the data parameter for a PSBT?

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, bip174-psbt

I am sure this is a dumb question but if using:

`bitcoin-cli walletcreatefundedpsbt "[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "[{\"data\":\"00010203\"}]"`

How do you create the data parameter? Where does it come from?

`\"00010203\"`

Edit:

I should have read the BIP first, it looks like it is an unsigned tx. So in order to create a PSBT you need to first create an unsigned tx? And include the hex as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PSBT contains an unsigned transaction that has all of the inputs and output that you want. The other data PSBT allows for are put in around that unsigned transaction.

Here, `data` just means that the unsigned transaction will have an output that has an `OP_RETURN` followed by whatever data you want. This directly reflects what `createrawtransaction`. `data` is not specific to PSBT nor is it necessary.

Comment: Thanks again Andrew, and thanks for your great contributions.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! it would be useful to specify it a little better in the "help", because now it seems the parameter is mandatory and it is not trivial to find this useful post.